# how to reload store and refresh chart after interval 60000 ms

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a chart with a renederer and after 10ms it will be reloaded and refreshes my chart.

```
var RunMinuteur = new Ext.util.TaskRunner(),
task = RunMinuteur.start({
    run: function() {
            ListeBarStore.reload();
            ListePieStore.reload();
            ListeBarStoreFinal.reload();
            Ext.getCmp('IDChartProgress').refresh();
    },
    interval: 60000
});
```

But after the 60000ms, it will not redraw the chart. Do you know why?

Comment: have you checked your store is data is updating or not ? because  [store.reload()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html) Reloads the store using the last options passed to the method-load method. You can use the reload method to reload the store using the parameters from the last load() call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ExtjS [store.reload()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-reload) reloads the store using the last options passed to the method-load method. You can use the reload method to reload the store using the parameters from the last load() call.For example:

```
store.load({
    params : {
        userid : 22216
    }
});

//...

store.reload();
```

Here I have create an [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28tc) demo you can also check here.

Comment: hank you very much but I did not understand too much the example, can you help me on my code. I am really stuck on this problem thanks for your understanding

Comment: Can you please put your running code on [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) ?

Comment: You can make account with [sencha fourum](https://www.sencha.com/forum/register.php)

Comment: ok thank you very much in the fiddle :https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28vc

Comment: You code is not working properly. Pls make sure your code should working properly. if you getting any issue so can take help form here [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28tc).

For bar chart you can refer this link [Ext.chart.series.Bar](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.chart.series.Bar.html)

Comment: hi sorry i have a probleme and i want just help for you ..please

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28vt this fidl no worked because the renderer not worked thank you very much